# how to animate the movie clip on click on button in Flash AS2.0

Tags: flash, animation, actionscript-2, timeline

i design 5 button in flash  **home, about, profile, gallery, contact** with a movie clip symbol on right side.
now i want when i click on home button the movie clip come to home button on same position at right side, same when i click on about it comes to about & same for other buttons.
please help me & let me know how it is possible with action script 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make tweens. Better than a example, look at this tutorial :

http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/170/1/Flash-MX-2004-Undocumented-TweenEasing-Classes-Documented/Page1.html

Comment: exactly like this but i want that ball come to the button on which i click for ex. when i click on gallery button the ball comes to gallery. same for all buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the:

```
var begin = 20;
var end = 380;
```

These values represent the begin and end X position of the ball in the stage.
If you have your buttons for example in X = 50 ; y = 100; The example should be:

```
myButton_btn.onRelease = function() {
        tweenBall(mx.transitions.easing.Bounce.easeOut);
};
function tweenBall(easeType) {
        var begin_x = 470; //This should be the initial X position of the mc that you want to animate
        var end_x = 50;
        var begin_y = 100; //This should be the initial Y position of the mc that you want to animate
        var end_y = 100; 
        var time = 20;
        var mc = ball_mc;
        ballTween = new mx.transitions.Tween(mc, "_x", easeType, begin_x, end_x, time);
        ballTween = new mx.transitions.Tween(mc, "_y", easeType, begin_y, end_y, time);
}
```

Hope it Helps !!